# How to check if an element has not a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="parent" id="1">
    <div class="childrens">
        <p> etc... </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent" id="2">
    <p> etc... </p>
</div>
```

I want to check if a `div.parent` does not contain a child element called `.childrens`, so if not add `div.childrens` and `wrapAll` childrens inside this div.

This is what I tried ([see this **jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6PY29/1/)):

```
$(".container").find(".parent").each(function() {
    if(!$(".parent").find('.childrens').length){
        $(".parent").children().wrapAll("<div class='childrens'></div>");
    }
});
```

but doesn't work. What I did wrong?
Any help is appreciated! Thank you so much and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: If a div.parent does not contains div.childrens add it and wrapAll childrens inside this div, this is what I expect to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for the each. You can use not, has, and wrapInner can solve it.

```
$(".container .parent").not(':has(".children")').wrapInner('<div class="childrens"></div>');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bWrsC/)

Another way to write it would be

```
$(".container .parent:not(:has(.children))").wrapInner('<div class="childrens"></div>');
```

---

The problem with your code is the fact you are reselecting all of the .parent elements again and not using `this` to work with the element that is currently being referenced on that iteration. Your code would need to look more like

```
$(".container").find(".parent").each(function() {
    var currentParent = $(this);
    if(!currentParent.find('.childrens').length){
        currentParent.children().wrapAll("<div class='childrens'></div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @epascarello, your solution to the problem is the shortest and better than others abd Thank you so much for good explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You should reference each parent container separately with `this`. Change your code to this:

```
$(".container").find(".parent").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).find('.childrens').length){
        $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class='childrens'></div>");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6PY29/3/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.parent` use `this`

```
$("#container").find(".parent").each(function() {
    if(!$(this).find('.childrens').length) {
        $(".parent").children().wrapAll("<div class='childrens'></div>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(!$(this).find('.childrens').length){
    $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class='childrens'></div>");
}
```

#### [Your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PY29/4/)

---

You have to target your current element with `$(this)` in your `.each()` iteration and you just targeted with it's className which looks for all classes available in the `#container`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the each loop you need to use $(this) to reference the current `parent` element. Currently you are checking all `parent` elements:

```
$("#container").find(".parent").each(function() {
     if(!$(this).find('.childrens').length){
          $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class='childrens'></div>");
     }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6PY29/2/

Also, your fiddle didn't have jQuery selected in the options so would never have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.parent').filter(function (){
    return !$(this).find('.children').length;
}).each(function (){
    $(this).contents().wrapAll('<div class="children"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".container").find(".parent").each(function() {
    var parent = $(this);
    if(!parent.find('.childrens').length){
        parent.children().wrapAll("<div class='childrens'></div>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$(".container").find(".parent").each(function() {
  if(!$(this).find('.childrens').length){
   $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class='childrens'></div>");
  }
});
```